# What is the "correct" way to pass a boolean to a Python C extension?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

This is a simple example from the python documentation (http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html):

```
static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}
```

If I want to pass an additional boolean parameter to the function - what's the "correct" way to do it?

There doesn't seem to be a bool option to pass to PyArg_ParseTuple(). So I thought of the following:

1. read an integer and just use the value (as bool is a subclass of int)
2. call PyBool_FromLong() on an integer
3. read and object and call PyBool_Check() to verify it is a bool
4. maybe there's a way to get any type of variable and get its truth value (i.e an empty array will is falsy etc.) which is what python function usually do.

Any of these preferable? Other options?

Comment: A completion of the topic 'bool' for Python/C is  **Py_RETURN_TRUE** and **Py_RETURN_FALSE** where you want to return a bool from C/C++.  The macros should be used to increment references.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> 4 maybe there's a way to get any type of variable and get its truth value (i.e an empty array will is falsy etc.) which is what python
>   function usually do.

Yes: (from [Python/C API Reference](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html))

> ```
> int PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *o)
> ```
>
> Returns 1 if the object o is considered to be true, and 0 otherwise.
>   This is equivalent to the Python expression not not o. On failure,
>   return -1.

EDIT. To answer the actual question, I think approach 1 is correct, because int really is the corresponding type in C. Approach 4 is good, but if you document your function as taking a bool, you are not obligated to accept just any object. Explicit type checks as in 3 without a reason are frowned upon in Python. Conversion to another Python object as in 2 does not help your C code.

Answer (score 21):

Currently, parsing an integer (as `"i"`) is the accepted way to take a bool.

From Python 3.3, `PyArg_ParseTuple` will accept `"p"` (for "predicate"), per [the latest NEWS](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05274ab06182/Misc/NEWS):

> - [Issue #14705](http://bugs.python.org/issue14705): The PyArg_Parse() family of functions now support the 'p' format
>   unit, which accepts a "boolean predicate" argument.  It converts any Python
>   value into an integer--0 if it is "false", and 1 otherwise.

Note that when using `PyArg_ParseTuple` with `"p"`, the argument must be a (pointer to) `int`, not the C99 `bool` type:

```
int x;    // not "bool x"
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "p", &x);
```

Comment: I've been using this and found that in C I must declare variables as `int` (not `bool`). Or, when using multiple bools, they will not get set correctly (possibly an issue with the difference in sizes between a `bool` and an `int`).

Comment: @szmoore It states that it uses an integer in the response here.

Comment: Yes it does, but often in C you can use `int` and `bool` interchangeably, in this case you cannot. I can remove my comment if it is superflous.

Comment: @szmoore sorry, I missed your original comment. That's an important point and I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have found another approach:

```
PyObject* py_expectArgs;
bool expectArgs;

PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, (char *)"O!", (char **)kwlist, &PyBool_Type, &py_expectArgs);

expectArgs = PyObject_IsTrue(py_expectArgs);
```

In case of wrong param call there is "auto" exception "argument 1 must be bool, not int"