# Wrap Complex C++ Class using the Python Extension API

Tags: python, c++, class, binding, wrapper

I'm pretty new to creating C++ class that I can use from within Python. I've skimmed through a lot of posts on the internet. Be it on StackOverflow, gist, github, ... I've also read the documentation, but I'm not sure how I can solve my issue.

Basically, the idea is to do this: http://www.speedupcode.com/c-class-in-python3/
As I want to avoid the burden of creating my own [python newtype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), I thought that using `PyCapsule_New` and `PyCapsule_GetPointer` as in the example above could be a workaround, but maybe I'm misleading, and I still need to create complex datatype.

Here is the header of my class I want to be able to call from python:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Graph {
    public:
        Graph(const vector3D<T>& image, const std::string& similarity, size_t d) : img(image) {...}
        component<T> method1(const int k, const bool post_processing=true);

    private:
        caller_map<T> cmap;
        vector3D<T> img;  // input image with 3 channels
        caller<T> sim;  // similarity function
        size_t h;  // height of the image
        size_t w;  // width of the image
        size_t n_vertices;  // number of pixels in the input image
        size_t conn;  // radius for the number of connected pixels
        vector1D<edge<T>> edges;  // graph = vector of edges

        void create_graph(size_t d);
        tuple2 find(vector2D<subset>& subsets, tuple2 i);
        void unite(vector2D<subset>& subsets, tuple2 x, tuple2 y);
};
```

So As you can see my class contains complex structures. `vector1D` is just `std::vector` but edge is a structure defined by

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct edge {
    tuple2 src;
    tuple2 dst;
    T weight;
};
```

and some methods use other complex structures.

Anyway, I have created my own Python binding. Here I only put the relevant functions. I created my `constructor` as follow:

```cpp
static PyObject *construct(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    // Arguments passed from Python
    PyArrayObject* arr = nullptr;

    // Default if arguments not given
    const char* sim = "2000";   // similarity function used
    const size_t conn = 1;  // Number of neighbor pixels to consider

    char *keywords[] = {
        "image",
        "similarity",
        "d",
        nullptr
    };

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "O&|sI:vGraph", keywords, PyArray_Converter, &arr, &sim, &conn)) {
        // Will need to DECRF(arr) somewhere?
        return nullptr;
    }

    set<string> sim_strings = {"1976", "1994", "2000"};

    if (sim_strings.find(sim) == sim_strings.end()) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "This similarity function does not exist");
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }

    // Parse the 3D numpy array to vector3D
    vector3D<float> img = parse_PyArrayFloat<float>(arr);

    // call the Constructor
    Graph<float>* graph = new Graph<float>(img, sim, conn);

    // Create Python capsule with a pointer to the `Graph` object
    PyObject* graphCapsule = PyCapsule_New((void * ) graph, "graphptr", vgraph_destructor);

    // int success = PyCapsule_SetPointer(graphCapsule, (void *)graph);
    // Return the Python capsule with the pointer to `Graph` object
    // return Py_BuildValue("O", graphCapsule);
    return graphCapsule;
}
```

While debugging my code, I can see that my constructor return my graphCapsule object and that it is different from `nullptr`.

then I create my `method1` function as follow:

```cpp
static PyObject *method1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    // Capsule with the pointer to `Graph` object
    PyObject* graphCapsule_;

    // Default parameters of the method1 function
    size_t k = 300;
    bool post_processing = true;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|Ip", &graphCapsule_, &k, &post_processing)) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Get the pointer to `Graph` object
    Graph<float>* graph = reinterpret_cast<Graph<float>* >(PyCapsule_GetPointer(graphCapsule_, "graphptr"));

    // Call method1
    component<float> ctov = graph->method1(k, post_processing);

    // Convert component<float> to a Python dict (bad because we need to copy?)
    PyObject* result = parse_component<float>(ctov);

    return result;
}
```

When I compile everything, I will have a `vgraph.so` library and I will call it from Python using:

```py
import vgraph
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

class Vgraph():
    def __init__(self, img, similarity, d):
        self.graphCapsule = vgraph.construct(img, similarity, d)

    def method1(self, k=150, post_processing=True):
        vgraph.method1(self.graphCapsule, k, post_processing)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = scipy.misc.imread("pic.jpg")
    img = scipy.misc.imresize(img, (512, 512)) / 255

    g = Vgraph(lab_img, "1976", d=1)
    cc = g.method1(k=150, post_processing=False)
```

The idea is that I save the `PyObject pointer` returned by the `vgraph.construct`. Then I call `method1` passing the `PyObject pointer` the `int k = 150` and the `bool postprocessing`.

This is why in the C++ implementation of `*method1`, I use:
`!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|Ip", &graphCapsule_, &k, &post_processing)` to parse these 3 objects.

The problem is, even though, when I'm debugging, I recover `k=150` and `post_processing=False` which come from the way I'm calling the C++ from Python... I'm also getting a `0X0`, that is to say a `nullptr` in the variable `graphCapsule_`...

So obviously the rest of the code cannot work...

I thought that `PyObject *` is a pointer to my **graph** of type `Graph<float> *`, so, I was expecting ParseTuple to recover my `PyObject *` pointer that I can then use in `PyCapsule_GetPointer` to retrieve my Object.

How can I make my code work? Do I need to define my own PyObject so that ParseTuple understand it? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

**Note**: If I break in my python code, I can see that my graph `g` contains a `PyObject` with the address it points to and the name of the object (here `graphtr`) so I was expecting my code to work...

**Note2**: If I need to create my own `newtype`, I have seen this stackoverflow post: [How to wrap a C++ object using pure Python Extension API (python3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786693/how-to-wrap-a-c-object-using-pure-python-extension-api-python3) but I think because of the complex objects of my Class, it will be quite difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

I actually found the flaw in my code.

Both functions `PyCapsule_GetPointer` and `PyCapsule_New` work perfectly fine. As mentioned in my question, the issue arouse just after I was trying to Parse the capsule with the following code:

```cpp
size_t k = 300;
bool post_processing = true;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|Ip", &graphCapsule_, &k, &post_processing)) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

The problem comes from the parsing of the other parameters.
Indeed, k is a `size_t` type so instead of using `I` for unsigned int, I should use `n` as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) mentions:

```
n (int) [Py_ssize_t]
Convert a Python integer to a C Py_ssize_t.
```

Moreover, `post_processing` is a boolean so, even though the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) mentions that a boolean can be parsed with a `p`:

```
p (bool) [int]
```

I should initialize the boolean with type `int` instead of type `bool` as it is mentioned in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700727/2683177)

So, the working piece of code is:

```cpp
size_t k = 300;
int post_processing = true;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|np", &graphCapsule_, &k, &post_processing)) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

We can also use the `O!` options by passing the `&Pycapsule_Type`:

```cpp
#include <pycapsule.h>
...
size_t k = 300;
int post_processing = true;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!|np", &PyCapsule_Type, &graphCapsule_, &k, &post_processing)) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Finally, as mentioned in my question, It is actually straightforward to implement your own Python type based on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48789494/2683177). I have just copied/pasted and adapted the code to my need and it works like a charm without need to use `PyCaspule` anymore!

**Other useful pieces of information**:

To debug your code (I used vscode on Linux), you can used mixed language debugging. The idea is to compile your C++ code into as shared library `.so`.

Once you're code is compiled you can import it in python:

```py
import my_lib
```

where `my_lib` referred to `my_lib.so` file that you have generated.

To generate your `.so` file, you just need to execute:
`g++ my_python_to_cpp_wrapper.cpp --ggdb -o my_python_to_cpp_wrapper.so`

But, if you do this, you might missed to include the python library and stuff...

Fortunately, python provide a way to find the recommended flags for both **compilation** and **linking**:

you just need to execute (change your python version or look into /usr/local/bin eventually)

```
/usr/bin/python3.6m-config --cflags
```

For me, it returned:

```sh
-I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-0aiVHW/python3.6-3.6.9=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
```

The same applying for linking (change your python version or look into /usr/local/bin eventually)

```
/usr/bin/python3.6m-config --ldflags
```

gave me:

```
-L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Then, since we want to create a shared library `.so` we need to add the `-shared` flag as well as the `-fPIC` flags (otherwise it will complain). Finally, since we want to debug our code we should remove any `-Ox` such as `-O2` or `-O3` flag that optimizes the code, because during the debugging you will be prompt with `<optimized out>`. To avoid this, remove any optimization flags from your `g++` options. For example, in my case, my **cpp** file is called: **vrgaph.cpp** and here is how I compiled it:

```sh
g++ vgraph.cpp -ggdb -o vgraph.so -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-0aiVHW/python3.6-3.6.9=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Wall -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -shared -fPIC
```

You can see I'm usin `-O1` instead of `-O2` or `-O3`.

Once, compile you will have a `.so` file that you can import and use in python. For my example, I will have `vgraph.so` and in my python code, I can do:

```py
import vgraph.so

# rest of the call that use you C++ backend code
```

Then you can easily debug your C++. There are some posts on the internet that explains how to do that with vs code/gdb/...